# Symfony 3 radio input name change

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, radiobuttonlist

I have a form which has a form (**CustomerVatsType**) for an entity (**CustomerVats**). This entity has a column (**vats**), which contains multiple vat rows. These rows are saved in json format. On this form, customer can choose a default vat, which will be saved in "**default**" index of rows saved in units column.

but problem is that radio input name is "**form[vats][0][set_default]**" due to structure of form. But for radio input to work correctly it needs to be same for all inputs (e.g. **form[vats][set_default]**). I can change name in twig file but then form class can not understand this.

What can be done for this situation. Does even Symfony support it. Here is my form class.

```
class VatsType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('vats', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => VatType::class,
                'allow_add'    => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'prototype'    => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
            )
        )
        ->add('vatSumbit', SubmitType::class);
    }
}


class VatType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('country_id', HiddenType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('vat_high', HiddenType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('vat_low', HiddenType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('vat_zero', HiddenType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('vat_none', HiddenType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('set_default', RadioType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('set_show', RadioType::class, array('label' => false));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think If you set the field name in twig you can bind the response field with form field, use handleRequest to do this.

Comment: @AshishAwasthi. . I changed the field name so it gave error that fields are not present in post. How can I change post data in handleRequest .. Do I need FormEventSubscriber . . can you provide some resource which I can refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following fix for this problem. It seems bit dirty but made most sense to because I dont want to confuse other devs with some really difficult method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (document, window, $) {
        $('[data-radio-field]').change(function () {
            var field = $(this).data('radio-field');
            $('[data-radio-field="' + field + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
        });
    })(document, window, jQuery);
</script>
```

If anyone can suggest a clean method, they are welcome to answer it. I think it should be a common problem. Would like to see other approaches well.